# Run a regex on a Supply or other stream-like sequence?

Tags: raku

Suppose I have a [`Supply`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Supply), [`Channel`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Channel), [`IO::Handle`](https://docs.raku.org/type/IO::Handle), or similar stream-like source of text, and I want to scan it for substrings matching a regex. I can't be sure that matching substrings do not cross [`chunk boundaries`](https://docs.raku.org/type/IO::Handle#method_Supply). The total length is potentially infinite and cannot be slurped into memory.

One way this would be possible is if I could instantiate a regex matching engine and feed it chunks of text while it maintains its state. But I don't see any way to do that -- I only see methods to run the match engine to completion.

Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe useful? Using `JSON::Stream` module to parse corrupt JSON: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/707180/227738 .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After some more searching, I may have answered my own question. Specifically, it seems [`Seq.comb`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Seq#(Cool)_routine_comb) is capable of combining chunks and lazily processing them:

```
my $c = supply {
  whenever Supply.interval(1.0) -> $v {
    my $letter = do if ($v mod 2 == 0) { "a" } else { "b" };
    my $chunk = $letter x ($v + 1);
    say "Pushing {$chunk}";
    emit($chunk);
  }
};

my $c2 = $c.comb(/a+b+/);

react {
  whenever $c2 -> $v {
    say "Got {$v}";
  }
}
```

See also the [concurrency features](https://docs.raku.org/language/concurrency) used to construct this example.

Comment: FWIW, most methods that have an iterable equivalent, combine chunks before processing, such as `lines` and `words`.